# making a good image carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a image carousel on my site as a header. The problem is that the images have a good cut out with a 4:3 monitor, on a few images a bad cutout at 1080p and a very bad cutout at 1440p. What can I do to fix this? How can I for example choose a area of the picture that is shown and scale this bigger if the viewport gets bigger.

If you resize the browser you will see what I mean.

Ps: If viewed via this code snipped you must be in full screen. Better would be visiting [my website here (port 3000)](http://guerillagaming.eu:3000/).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000" data-pause="false">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 500px">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/jHM0Qfx.jpg" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/4jCNs81.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/PbIngUg.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/DU4B2kz.jpgg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/XYBEDye.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: IrfanView is a free to download software. 1.0 Go to File and choose Open to upload the image. 2.0 Go to Image and then choose Resize/Resample. 3.0 At Resize/Resample image, choose Desktop size and then click Ok. That's it

Comment: @hans-könig what?

Answer (score 0):

css `object-fit: cover` is definitely your best friend here !

Don't forget to set the elements in between the image and the container to cover the caroussel's container and voila:

```css
.carousel-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-item img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000" data-pause="false">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 500px">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/jHM0Qfx.jpg" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/4jCNs81.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/PbIngUg.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/DU4B2kz.jpgg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/XYBEDye.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Best Example for Slideshow/Carousel***

[A Good Slideshow Using HTML, JS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

[Carousel Using Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)